# I upgraded to ubuntu lucid and now flash won't work in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, flash, ubuntu-10.04, chromium

I just upgraded to lucid, and now flash won't work in chrome (though it works in firefox). I even switched over to the dev channel, which supposedly has flash built in, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure flashplugin-installer
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried going back to [Adobe's Flash Installer](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/otherversions/) page and adding the `APT for Ubuntu 9.04+` version again.

This may force an update and fix Chrome.

Comment: tried that and I get an popup afterward saying adobe-flashplugin in virtual or something to that effect